Analysis of ramp generator with BJT PNP
Based on this post/discussion and also on this article I was trying to make an analysis of the circuit and also build my own circuit soon. However I could not really understand the choice of components and their values. Taking the circuit from the article as example:

(for the sake of simplification I am ignoring the "ramp-down" part of the circuit and am only interested on the "ramp-up" analysis)
Simulating this circuit, it gives me indeed a nice-looking ramp where the capacitor gets charged at ~ 7uA rate with the peak just a tiny bit below 6v:
 
So far so good, but how were all the values from components chosen? Measuring the Vbe during charge also points that it does not even reach 0.5V. So I decided designing the same circuit from scratch using some approaches I've read from other sources:

Let's consider I want to charge my capacitor at a 5uA rate (to facilitate the math) using the same 6V source.
So the first approach was defining the bias of my PNP. Considering Ic to be 5uA I used the rule of thumb of Ic/10 to be the current through the bias resistors which gives me 12M of resistance in total (R1 and R2).
Then I should decide the emitter resistor value R3. Considering that I want the emitter to be at 1V below the source as a starting point following the logic of a common emitter amplifier (even though I do not have AC signal here), then I would have the R3 to be 200k.
Having Ve=5V from point 3 I can now calculate R1, considering Vbe=0.7 and Ve=5V, than I have a drop of 1.7V across R1, which leads me to a value of 3.4M
Based on point 4 and 2 I can also define R2 now to be 8.6M.

Resulting circuit:


From the chart above we can see it is coherent as it is charging with approx 5uA and also achieving 5.8V. However, when reaching the top it does not stop immediately (red circle region), but rather smoothly. I assume this is probable due to step 3: when Vce gets close to 0V the current starts to drop so the voltage drop across R3 also drops simultaneously until both reach ~0.
So perhaps I should remove the emitter resistor R3 and recalculate R1 and R2 using the voltage drop across R1 to be 0.7V, which leads me to R1=1.4M and therefore R2=10.6M (to keep current across them to be 0.5uA), leading to the following circuit and results:


So we can see it fixed now so that it cuts the ramp as expected, however the charging current jumped to ~16uA. So I am confused about the best approach to solve this problem analytically. First problem I found out on the original circuit is that considering Vcc=6V, R1=1k and R2=10k would lead us to a bias voltage of ~5.54V which would imply that Vbe can be max. 0.46V, which is lower than 0.7V. That would mean, in my understanding, that we are operating in the most non-linear part of the PN junction and therefore it will be very dependent on the transistor  intrinsic characteristics. However, on my first design attempt (using R3=200k), simulation shows me Vbe also does not achieve 0.7V, but rather ~ 0.46V, even though the design was considering the Vbe=0.7V. I assume this is due to very low currents that are achieved before reaching the 0.7V across a PN junction. That may also explain the last example without R3, which also has Vbe=0.49V and 4x the calculated Ic. So my questions are:
a. For such a circuit, do I really need the R3? If yes, what for?
b. How do I actually design/calculate the values (with or without R3) of the resistors considering such small currents, so that simulation stays coherent to expected/calculated values?
c. (related to question b.) Can someone explain the choices of the original circuit values somehow?

The original circuit at 7 uA and your desired 5 uA are pretty close, yet you’ve changed the resistor values by three orders of magnitude. That’s generally a sign that something is amiss.

Felipe, You can design a reasonable current source/sink that works over a temperature range and part variations that provides a current into a capacitor. This can be followed by a Schmitt trigger that drives a output (as shown there) switch that shorts the capacitor to restart the cycle. This would be 5 BJTs and can be designed within perhaps 5% to 10% over parts and temperature with discretes.

I would say this circuit is not particularly well designed. The synthetic PUJT circuit as shown does not allow the output to rise above about 3.6V. We have a 6V supply so we can devote at least 2V to the constant-current source.
I would use something more like this, for an approximately 5uA source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The arrangement shown in the question is very dependent on Vbe of the transistor, so it will be unnecessarily sensitive to temperature and individual transistor characteristics.
I've picked the voltage across R2 to be about 2V. Since Vbe will be about 0.6V (maybe a bit less since the base current will be very low) then the voltage across R1 is thus about 1.4V. We pick R1 to be 1.4V/5uA = 280kΩ so the compliance of the voltage source will be from below ground to about 6V-1.5V (assuming saturation at Vce around 100mV) or 4.5V, which is well above 3.6V.
We could even go a bit higher, but this has much better margin than the original. There's no reason (other than possible power saving) to have high values for R2/R3, it will just introduce unnecessary dependency on the transistor hFE.
Compare this simulation over temperature of the two circuits (pink is the original, green is my circuit):

My circuit varies from about 4.7uA at -40°C to about 6uA at +120°C.
The original circuit varies from 13nA at -40°C to 19uA at +120°C (so it stops working, for practical purposes, when cold).
Increasing the voltage across R1 will improve that- the limit being set by how high you need the voltage across C1 to increase.
It can be temperature-compensated with a diode-connected transistor in the divider chain. Or add a suitable op-amp and make it almost perfect.

There's a problem with the original design, which I'll address at the end, and which makes it impossible to say how the author came up with those resistor values. I suspect they are made up and tweaked until the thing works. Instead of doing that, here is a design process, my thoughts at each step, which should illustrate the purpose and reasoning behind each decision.
First examine the base current you expect from this setup. You can calculate approximate base current \$I_B\$ using the transistor's current gain, \$\beta\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_C &= \beta \times I_B \\ \\
I_B &= \frac{I_C}{\beta}
\end{aligned}
$$
As a rough guess, using \$\beta=100\$,, and assuming collector current is of the order of \$I_C=10\mu A\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_B &= \frac{I_C}{\beta} \\ \\
&= \frac{10\mu A}{100} \\ \\
&= 100nA
\end{aligned}
$$
That's tiny. This will determine the transistor's base-emitter junction voltage \$V_{BE}\$, which will be useful information later. A little simulation will show how that voltage varies with base current \$I_B\$:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Often we say that \$V_{BE}\approx 0.7V\$, but that's only true for base currents in the tens or hundreds of microamps. We are going to be operating way below that, and as you can see, when \$I_B\approx 100nA\$, \$V_{BE}\approx 0.5V\$, so that's the value we will use.
Your transistor is configured as an emitter follower, otherwise called common-collector, and we expect emitter potential \$V_E\$ to rise and fall with the base, "following" it so to speak, but always \$V_{BE}=0.5V\$ (in this case) higher than the base:
$$ V_E = V_B + 0.5V $$
It may look like this is common-emitter, but we depend on emitter follower action for this design to work. By setting base potential, we indirectly also set emitter potential, and by setting emitter potential we also control the voltage across R3, which I will call \$V_{R3}\$. This is what determines emitter current \$I_E\$, and because base current is so small in comparison (\$\beta\$ times smaller), we can make the assumption:
$$ I_C \approx I_E = \frac{V_{R3}}{R_3} $$
R3 voltage \$V_{R3}\$ is this potential difference:
$$ V_{R3} = 6V - V_E $$
We don't want a large \$V_{R3}\$, because it will limit the maximum voltage that the collector can attain, and consequently the maximum voltage to which the capacitor can charge. A good target would be 1V, leaving \$6V-1V=5V\$ for the capacitor. Since you require \$I_C=7\mu A\$, Ohm's law tells us the correct value for R3:
$$ R_3 = \frac{1V}{7\mu A} = 143k\Omega $$
To have 1V across R3 will require emitter potential to be:
$$ V_E = 6V - V_{R3} = 6V - 1V = +5V $$
Being an emitter follower, and having already found \$V_{BE}\$, we can now find the required base potential \$V_B\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_E &= V_B + V_{BE} \\ \\
V_B &= V_E - V_{BE} \\ \\
&= +5V - 0.5V \\ \\
&= +4.5V
\end{aligned}
$$
It remains, then, to find a pair of resistances R1 and R2 that produce this base potential:
$$
\begin{aligned}
6V \times \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} &= 4.5V \\ \\
\frac{R_1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{3} \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
It's important to consider base current again here, because that current will influence the +4.5V potential produced by the R1 & R2 divider. We need to ensure that current \$I_{DIV}\$ in those resistors is much, much larger than \$I_B\$, by a factor of perhaps 100 or 1000, to minimise that influence:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{DIV} &= 100nA \times 1000 \\ \\
&= 100\mu A \\ \\
I_{DIV} &= \frac{6V}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
100\mu A &= \frac{6V}{R_1 + R_2} \\ \\
R_1 + R_2 &= \frac{6V}{100\mu A} \\ \\
&= 60k\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$
Solving those simultaneous equations we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1 &= 15k\Omega \\ \\
R_2 &= 45k\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
This is the design, then:

simulate this circuit
With C1 charging from constant current, we expect a nice straight ramp up to 5V or so:

During that charge, current should be a constant 7μA:

Not quite, that's more like 6.5μA, because of the various assumptions and approximations we made on the way. It's easy to tweak though.
We could lower R2, to increase the voltage across R3, or we could decrease R3. R3 is the more "direct" way to modify current, so that's what I'll do here. To increase emitter current \$I_E\$ by 7%, decrease R3 by 7%:
$$ R_3 = 143k\Omega \times 93\% = 133k\Omega $$
Changing R3 to 133kΩ produces this current curve:

Much better. It turns out, for this particular transistor and the resistor values we calculated, \$R_3=143k\Omega\$ will produce \$I_C=6.5\mu A\$. Using that as a starting value, you can modify R3 to produce any \$I_C\$ within reason. Doubling R3 to 286kΩ will halve that current to 3.2μA, for instance. This is how you could calculate R3 given some target \$I_C\$:
$$ R_3 \approx 143k\Omega \times \frac{6.5\mu A}{I_C} $$

I think the biggest issue you have is in your choice of R1 and R2. Your values are in the megohms, passing a tiny amount of current. That current is responsible for setting base potential, and if you then divert a comparable current (100nA or so) into the transistor's base, then that potential is going to be severely perturbed. This is why I chose R1 and R2 to be kilohms, so that divider current is very large compared to base current. In this way, the potential produced by the R1 & R2 divider is much "stiffer", and more difficult to influence. Attaching the transistor's base should then have negligible effect.
A word about your question (a), is R3 necessary? I hope the answer is now clear: YES, that resistor directly determines current. You could omit it, but then the resulting current would depend on transistor characteristics such as \$\beta\$, which change from transistor to transistor, and even with temperature and age. The presence of R3 mitigates dependency on exact transistor characteristics, permitting you to obtain behaviour based on more dependable, controllable and predictable resistor values. The technique is called "emitter degeneration".
The values for R1 and R2 in the original schematic are not appropriate, since they produce a base potential of:
$$ 6V \times \frac{10}{1+10} = 5.45V $$
This is too high, and emitter potential will not be well defined. A simulation may show it working, but exact capacitor current is impossible to predict.
Also, the author uses a capital "K" to signify "kilo", which is already a red flag.

Thanks for the explanations. That's more or less what I had in mind, except for 2 points: finding Ib when considering Vbe=~0.5V is what I mentioned with "operating in the most non-linear part of the PN junction and being depedent on the instrinsic characteristics". So yes, I can understand your chart and how you found this value, but isnt it a value that will be always different because it will depend on the specific transistor (not even the model/family but the part itself) I am using at the project? So replacing the transistor by the same model may give me 200nA instead of 100nA for example

The other point is, I was aware of the bias resistos current and agree with what you say (was also my approach) but I've read more than one time that a good rule of thumb is just considering this current at least 10x bigger than the Ib, that's why I ended up with Mega-ohms resistor, because I also want to reduce consumption in general. So you're saying the order of 10x bigger is still not big enough, therefore you consider 100x or even 1000x bigger?

Just one more observation to the first question: how to extract this information (Ib for smaller forward voltages) from a given transistor, since that is usually not to be found on datasheet, without having to simulate it?

The R3 strongly removes the Ic Beta dependency. Whether the Beta is 200 or 300 the charging current (or Ic) is about the same.
Note: The Beta fly about 20% in -20+40degC temperature range.
Also, without R3 you would need to adjust base resistors for every single transistor according its manufactured Beta.

What you have is a current source that works by using the emitter resistor to set a bias point based on current. While the emitter resistor helps by compensating for some of the beta variation, it’s not so great what you have there. We can do better.
Here’s more about current sources: https://www.planetanalog.com/an-analog-tutorial-current-sources/
A good, simple one is the Widlar source, which is also known as a current mirror. The typical circuit shown is a low-side sink with two NPNs. We can make it a source by substituting PNPs and flipping it over. As below (simulate it here):

You can vary the charge rate by changing the the bias current reference resistor at lower left. With the reference resistor at 750k it's set for about 7.2uA. This current is mirrored on the right hand transistor.
I modified the pseudo-PUJT circuit so that the waveform doesn't go below GND, and swings up to 5.7V.
Speaking of which, here's a useful page about PUJTs, with several options for making ramp oscillators. 'Step 8' shows a current mirror.
